# Battery or alternater went bad

Tags: alternator

Is it true if I take the cord off the negitve side of battery n it dies, dose that mean my alternater is bad

Comment: Welcome to the site. No, it does not necessarily. Depending what vehicle you are working on, some damage can be done by doing so. If you **[edit]** your question to add details about the vehicle, we can try to give you a specific answer.

Comment: A search gave this question and answers : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/33706/10976

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the specific car. The best way to diagnose it is to take the car to a parts store of your choice (or even a Walmart tire department). They have equipment to diagnose whether it's the alternator, battery, or (frequently) both.